# I lose my static data on my app after calling google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm developing an application with a list of stores. For each store, using the google services API (v2) I can open and display the map and add a marker to the store location.
Everything works fine. I can return to the list and pick another store. 
All the data is being stored in static array lists.

**The problem**:
When I'm on the google map, if I click in the marker and then on the button to get the directions (implemented by the google map) it opens the Google Maps app and displays the route. Then, when I return, I'll my data is lost! All arraylists become null.

And idea? Thank you.

Comment: You need to save that data in onPause(), so you can restore it onResume() http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/components/activities.html):

> An activity can exist in essentially three states:
>
> (...)
>
> **Stopped**
>
> The activity is completely obscured by another activity (the
>   activity is now in the "background"). A stopped activity is also still
>   alive (the Activity object is retained in memory, it maintains all
>   state and member information, but is not attached to the window
>   manager). However, it is no longer visible to the user and it can be
>   killed by the system when memory is needed elsewhere.

Thus, as your Activity is stopped according to this definition, if the device has not enough memory (or it is needed by another task), or if in the "Developer Options" of the "Settings" menu the option called "Don't keep activities" (that destroys the activities as the user leaves it) is checked, your Activity will be killed and all your static fields will be lost.

To avoid this, you may want to ensure that your Activity's state is saved so you can restore ir later. Take a look at http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html